# How to import a constant from another module into a local function

Tags: python

I want to set a global `Debug` variable in a sibling module to `True` in a certain testcase.

Here is the structure of the `hercl` package

```
hercl
  |-- __init__.py
  |-- job_utils.py
  |-- pipeline.py (this file)
```

The global variable in  `job_utils.py`

```
  Debug = False
```

The referring code in `pipeline.py`

```
def herclShowDir(dir, glob):
    from . job_utils import Debug
    Debug = True   # grayed out : considered a local variable
```

I was unable to determine how to reference the `job_utils.Debug` variable within `pipeline.py` . Note: adding in `global Debug` within the inner function does not work: it refers back to the local variable not the one in `job_utils`). Also attempted:  `job_utils.Debug = True`

Why is `Debug` not identified as the same global variable from `job_utils.py` ?

Comment: Isn't your code giving you `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`. https://onlinegdb.com/TuyJkuQ2L

Comment: Since both of your files are in same directory, you should either import like `from job_utils import Debug` or `import job_utils`. For the later case you can access using `job_utils.Debug`.

Comment: @Avinash  No it just ignores the Debug setting. the code runs fine except Debug is not enabled .  I did already try the two statements you said : same result that Debug is seen as a local variable not the global one. It's strange.

Comment: in code in your link it has to be `from config import Debug` without `.`. Did you put `global Debug` inside function `herclShowDir`?

Comment: @furas I did have `global Debug` as the first attempt and it does not work. That was a surprise.  I did mention this in the question

Comment: but you didn't say if you set it outside function or inside function - and this makes big difference. `global` outside function is useless. `global` inside function inform function to assign new value to global variable.

Comment: ok i'll add that. yes it's inside function

Comment: After `from . job_utils import Debug`, there is now a name `Debug` in your own namespace, that has the same value as `Debug` had in the imported module.  *There is no further connection to the module*, assigning to `Debug` is only affecting your namespace.

Comment: To actually change the value in the module, you would need to do `import job_utils`, and then `job_utils.Debug = whatever`.

Comment: @jasonharper Yea I tried that too.  i was uncertain whether to put down all the permutations of what has been attempted. Probably I should